# Migrate content from drupal8 to drupal8 programmatically with Node::load and Node::create

Tags: 8, nodes, drush, migrations, console

Basicly I want to migrate content from one drupal8 instance to another. they are mostly identical with some small changes.

first step is to migrate the content type via `drush gen module` module and drupal-console `drupal config:export:content:type`

then i export the content type via script:

```
<?PHP
define('DRUPAL_DIR', __DIR__ . "/web");

use Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

require_once DRUPAL_DIR . '/core/includes/database.inc';
require_once DRUPAL_DIR . '/core/includes/schema.inc';
$autoloader = require_once DRUPAL_DIR . '/autoload.php';

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();

$kernel = DrupalKernel::createFromRequest($request, $autoloader, 'prod');
$kernel->boot();
$kernel->prepareLegacyRequest($request);

use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\Component\Serialization;
$serializer = \Drupal::service('serializer');

echo "Node Export Starting... \n\n";

// Nodes
$node_ids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->condition('type', 'content-type')->execute();
echo count($node_ids);
$single_nodes =  \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple($node_ids);
$data = $serializer->serialize($single_nodes, 'json');
file_put_contents('nodes.json', $data);
```

i serialize it and write it into a file.

on the new page I install the exported module to receive all fields for the content type + dependencies and so on.

if I try now to run my importer script i get serveral errors that the (exported) nodes can not be created.

```
 $json = json_decode(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . "/import/nodes.json"));
foreach ($json as $nid => $nodeImport) {
    $node = Node::create($nodeImport);
    $node->save();
}
```

Node::create() doesnt seems to accept whole exported/loaded NodeArrays nor casted arrays like `(array)$nodeImport`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using Migrate module for this task. For pulling entities from external database use [Drupal 8 migration](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_drupal_d8) module.